# Cassandra performance benchmarks on HDD storage

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Can anyone kindly share the performance benchmark for Cassandra on traditional HDD? Interested in the details of the impact and best practices associated with the same.

Assuming 3X the Read traffic than the Write traffic.

Comment: this heavily depends on the data model, queries executed, etc. You need to make question more specific...

Comment: Can you give some generic measurements around all these aspects?

Comment: look here as examples: https://github.com/jshook/perfscripts

Comment: @AlexOtt Actually I meant to say, that I was looking at generic measurements that somebody might have already done assuming the parameters that you raised like that of data model, queries, etc.

Comment: Look to link that I’ve sent...